# Parameterized test generate test data dynamically

Tags: junit, parameterized, test-data

I have a junit test method which i test against the parameterized generated data sets

```java
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection primeNumbers() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
         { readRequestFile(reqFile1), readResponseFile(resFile1)},
         { readRequestFile(reqFile2), readResponseFile(resFile2)},
         { readRequestFile(reqFile3), readResponseFile(resFile3)}
    });
}
```

As in above code the data sets are hard coded, i have a directory where the files are present i want to load these files in test data set dyamically something like

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->



 @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection primeNumbers () {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                    listOfRequestFiles = readAllRequestFilesFromTheResourceDirecotry
                    listOfResponseFiles = readAllResponseFilesFromTheResourceDirecotry

//lets say i read files from somewhere
listOfFiles = getAllfiles();
for (filename: listOfFiles) {
                //by some way this files should be available for testing data
            }
        });
    }
```

How can this be achieved , can somebody help

Comment: If you could switch to junit5, there is something like TestFactory, maybe it could be useful for you https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-dynamic-tests

Comment: I guess the TestFactory is for dynamic test cases, but in my case i am looking for generation of test data dynamically

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't understand the second code snippet. Can you add some types so that it is more clear what you try to achieve.